# Contact Form 7 get_posted_data not working in hook wpcf7_before_send_mail

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have borrowed this code from stackoverflow in attempt to find a solution. I need to create a new post from submitted data on a form. I was using the filter:

```
  add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'save_new_booked_event_data' );
```

but found that it fired after every submit and not AFTER validation. So I moved on to this code:

```
 add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','contactform7_before_send_mail',1);function 
    contactform7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) {       
         if ( !isset($contact_form->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission') ) {
                 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            if ( $submission ) {
                 $formData = $submission->get_posted_data();   
                 $formField = $formData['_wpcf7'];     
                 update_post_meta(199, 'first_name', $formField);
    }
} else {
    // We can't retrieve the form data
    return $contact_form;
}
   return $contact_form;
}
```

Five hours later: the get_posted_data method is always NULL. I ve tried approaching it from different angles including turning off ajax and posting the form. I've checked and dumped every object to make sure that it works but it always turns up NULL. What am I missing here? Please anyone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess:

The [`get_posted_data`](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/721fd1d81ff871d359f61131f34307970795b412/includes/submission.php#L60) method relies on [`setup_posted_data`](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/721fd1d81ff871d359f61131f34307970795b412/includes/submission.php#L72) firing, first, and [that occurs when the constructor for the `WPCF7_Submission` class is invoked](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/721fd1d81ff871d359f61131f34307970795b412/includes/submission.php#L27).

Perhaps there are multiple contact forms and your `contactform7_before_send_mail` function is hooked to one of them that hasn't been submitted, and therefore, the data are `null`.

That being the case, you could override and force population of posted data for your form if you pass an instance of `WPCF7_ContactForm` to the `WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();` call.

Something like:

```
$form       = new WPCF7_ContactForm($id_of_your_form);
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance($form);
```

By the way! Your snippet appears to be from [this wordpress plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/form-to-post/). (Form to Post) In case you want a more configurable solution, or to browse the context it lives in.

Comment: Hi Cameron, I tried passing an instance of the class with form id to submission get instance method but it crashed somewhere in the middle of the process. I have dumped the $submission and it has the correct for id but posted_data is null

Comment: What are the contents of $_POST? Maybe try dumping that in the hooked function, too! Just to be sure

Comment: Uhh, can you remind me of how to do that? $_POST['wpcf7-f196-p2-o1']? Please? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry brain freeze. I've been working on this too long..... $_POST['_wpcf7'] for example. I checked this $_POST posts the correct input in the action.